# Div tags moving along when zooming

Tags: html, css, tags, position, zooming

I am pretty new at HTML, and I am experimenting with some div tags to move along when zooming in or out the page. The structure of my HTML code is:

```
<header>
    
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Here goes a title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="logo" src="my/image/path.png">
            </div>
        </div>

</header>
```

And the corresponding CSS code:

```
header{ 
    padding-left: 260px;
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.title{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

img.logo{
    width: 243.77px;
    height: 73.43px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Both my title and the logo image moves when zooming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use the `padding-left` to change the position of the full header, but also you use the `px` unit which makes its position seems keep changing in different screen size.

A solution is to use percentage instead or use [media screen query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

An off-topic suggestion, it is not always a good practice to use `padding` to change position, use `margin` is always better.

*This is an example use percentage you could change based on what you want.

```css
header{ 
    padding-left: calc(20vw);
    padding-top:calc(5vh);
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: calc(10vh);
}

.title{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

img.logo{
    width: 243.77px;
    height: 73.43px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
    
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Here goes a title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="logo" src="my/image/path.png">
            </div>
        </div>

</header>
```